# Copy users and permissions Sharepoint 2010 to new Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, permissions

Does anyone have a simple (hopefully free) solution to copy users and permissions from an old SharePoint 2010 to a new SharePoint 2013 site? (I can move content with no issue).
This could be through powershell or via a software solution, much appreciated.

Comment: What about migration? :)

Comment: I don't mind migrating....but I would like to test first before migrating users and shutting down the original site.

Comment: okay so just make an copy of your 2010 database and add to your 2013 environment.... mount the database with "mount-spcontentdatabase"... than use move-spuser to migrate the users to your new environment... (be sure you enter the correct alias)

Comment: Ok I have now been told IT manager wants us to go from SP 2010 to SP 2016 and to using SQL server 2016 in background.....would Sharegate or a solution like that be our best bet? Just looking for the easiest less fuss method

Comment: in my opinion, the savest way is to migrate from 2010 to 2013 and then to 2016, cauze you cant migrate from 2010 to 2016 in one step...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, please try doing the migration following the scenario “Convert SharePoint 2010 Products classic-mode web applications to claim-based authentication in SharePoint 2010 Products and then upgrade to SharePoint 2013”:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also get help from this article for [SharePoint migration](http://expert-advice.org/2017/02/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2016/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I've done it with Sharegate before! If you don't mind migrating you can check out these docs: https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000597627-Copy-User-Permissions and https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000598267-Copy-Users probably the easiest/fastest way to do it and they have a free trial period too